# Calling application wsdl in .NET

Tags: .net, api, soap, https, wsdl

I have integration code built on .Net which communicates with my application Service Manager through SOAP API over HTTP.  Now the requirement is to move the integration over HTTPS.  For that, we have secured the communication over Service Manager through self-signed certificates.

On the SOAP UI app, I have the option to give client Keystore and its credentials to connect with the WSDL but don't know about .Net how to perform this.  Need help on this.

Thanks,
Zeeshan Malik